# Use Laravel Sanctum to add Authentication to Horizon

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, single-page-application

I wondering if it’s possible to use the SPA login(from Vue) using Laravel Sanctum to also authorise for Laravel Horizon?

I’ve done much googling and can’t find an answer to this. So far I’ve just had to make do with creating a custom middleware for Horizon that uses Auth.basic, which isn’t as user friendly as it would be to login via Sanctum and use the abilities to determine who can view Horizon dashboard.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

According to this GitHub Issue Comment:
https://github.com/laravel/horizon/issues/65#issuecomment-412128134

> Author: @francislavoie
>
> So this is kinda hilarious. I found out that Horizon has an
> undocumented feature to solve this.
>
> https://github.com/laravel/horizon/blob/1.0/src/HorizonServiceProvider.php#L54
>
> Horizon does try to grab its list of middlewares from config. This
> isn't documented anywhere unfortunately.
>
> You can simply add `'middleware' => ['web', 'auth']`, to your
> `config/horizon.php`.

So in my case, this became:

```
'middleware' => ['web','assign.guard:web','auth:sanctum'],
```

`assign.guard` is my own middleware because I have multiple auth guards going on.